# NoHttpResponseException issue on Android

Tags: android, exception, httpclient, android-async-http

I'm developing an Android app which uses [android-async-http](http://loopj.com/android-async-http/) as http client. My server is running ok but often when testing in my Android device (2.3.6) an exception raises:

```
org.apache.http.NoHttpResponseException: The target server failed to respond
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultResponseParser.java:85)
at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractMessageParser.parse(AbstractMessageParser.java:174)
at org.apache.http.impl.AbstractHttpClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(AbstractHttpClientConnection.java:179)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(DefaultClientConnection.java:235)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractClientConnAdapter.receiveResponseHeader(AbstractClientConnAdapter.java:259)
at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.doReceiveResponse(HttpRequestExecutor.java:279)
at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.execute(HttpRequestExecutor.java:121)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:421)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
at com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpRequest.makeRequest(AsyncHttpRequest.java:76)
at com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpRequest.makeRequestWithRetries(AsyncHttpRequest.java:95)
at com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpRequest.run(AsyncHttpRequest.java:57)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:444)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:306)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1088)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:581)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
```

Comment: It will be hard to debug this without seeing your code. Have you checked simple things like having the correct permissions (``INTERNET``) set in your ``AndroidManifest.xml``?

Comment: Close your Emulartor and restart it again, this will fix your problem

Comment: Yes, I have INTERNET permission in my manifest. This error occurs often but not everytime. I'm not using simulator, I'm using a real device.